# Log Return of data with 0s

Tags: dataset, logarithmic-scale

I am struggling with trying to normalise a dataset I have to use for other functions I have created. I have data that range from 0 to 80 000 and I want to transform this data either by making the return of it or the log return and then normalise it between 0 and 1. The normalisation step is pretty straightforward but the I am stuck with the calculation of the return of the data as there are some 0s and the return of multiple 0s is hard to handle.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Any advice??  "Don't take the log."

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "making the return of it"? It also helps *us* if you show what you have tried, and what exactly is the problem with this approch

Comment: I mean a transformation like the one described here: https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/extended-probability-and-statistics/log-returns-of-stock-prices.html?product=language except with 0s in the data. I guess I will just try another transfromation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about _Mathematica_, but seeks a ,athematical approach for data handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me from your post how you want to do the normalization. Here are two possibilities. Perhaps one will work for you.

Since you not provide an example of your data, I will use the following data for the purposes of exposition:

```
max = 80000.;
data =
  Module[{n = 20, min = -max/2},
    SeedRandom[1];
    Clip[#, {0., ∞}] & /@ RandomReal[{min, max}, n]]
```

> ```
> {58086.7, 0., 54743.1, 0., 0., 0., 25069.6, 0., 7520.73, 44056.9, 0., 
>  49838.8, 10742.1, 0., 77260.6, 59019.6, 71033., 29366.7, 0., 0.}
> ```

Here is what I think is likely what you want:

```
((Log /@ data) /. Indeterminate -> 0.)/Log[max]
```

> ```
> {0.971648, 0., 0.966397, 0., 0., 0., 0.897219, 0., 0.790575, 0.947161, 0., 
>  0.958083, 0.822153, 0., 0.996914, 0.973059, 0.98947, 0.911233, 0., 0.}
> ```

But you might want vector normalization, like this:

```
((Log /@ data) /. Indeterminate -> 0.) // Normalize
```

> ```
> {0.314433, 0., 0.312734, 0., 0., 0., 0.290347, 0., 0.255836, 0.306509, 0., 
>  0.310043, 0.266055, 0., 0.322609, 0.31489, 0.3202, 0.294882, 0., 0.}
> ```

Comment: Oh that's perfect! Thank you! It really helped what did there quite useful.

Comment: @Sisko. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Answer (score -1):

Try 
myNorm[x_]:=x/80000.0
Map[myNorm, data]

Comment: Or Log/@(data+1)